# Check gcc minor in cmake

Tags: gcc, build, cmake, cross-platform, version-detection

Is it possible to check the minor version number of GCC in cmake?

I want to do something like this:

```
If (GCC_MAJOR >= 4 && GCC_MINOR >= 3)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add a minimum compiler version requisite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933172/how-can-i-add-a-minimum-compiler-version-requisite)

Comment: If I am guessing your intentions correctly, this will mis-detect GCC 5.0, 5.1, 6.0, 6.1, etc.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use `if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 4.2)` as mentioned by onqtam. This obsolete answer was back from the 2.6 CMake days.

<strike>You could run `gcc -dumpversion` and parse the output. Here is one way to do that:</strike>

```
if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)
    execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} -dumpversion
                    OUTPUT_VARIABLE GCC_VERSION)
    string(REGEX MATCHALL "[0-9]+" GCC_VERSION_COMPONENTS ${GCC_VERSION})
    list(GET GCC_VERSION_COMPONENTS 0 GCC_MAJOR)
    list(GET GCC_VERSION_COMPONENTS 1 GCC_MINOR)

    message(STATUS ${GCC_MAJOR})
    message(STATUS ${GCC_MINOR})
endif()
```

That would print "4" and "3" for gcc version 4.3.1. However you can use CMake's version checking syntax to make life a bit easier and skip the regex stuff:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} -dumpversion
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE GCC_VERSION)
if (GCC_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 4.3 OR GCC_VERSION VERSION_EQUAL 4.3)
        message(STATUS "Version >= 4.3")
endif()
```

Comment: I found that really useful, thanks. Is there a way to strip the newline from version number ?

Comment: As of gcc 7, `-dumpversion` now outputs simply `7`, so this is broken. Prefer the answer by onqtam which is far more portable.

Comment: 2.8.10 has now the variable, but you may want to known that gcc has -dumpfullversion

Answer (score 26):

Combining the 2 other answers, you can check the specific gcc version as follows:

```
if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC AND CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 5.1)
    ...
endif()
```

Answer (score 24):

Since CMake 2.8.10 there are the `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_VERSION` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION` variables exactly for this purpose so you can do this:

```
if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 4.2)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: shorter, simpler, well-defined for all current and future compiler versions. The answer accepted right now (by richq) has a problem: `-dumpversion` now returns `7` in gcc 7, so it's a broken solution.

Answer (score 1):

However, there is an argument, `-dumpfullversion` that provides the full version string.

```
gcc -dumpfullversion
```

should get what you want. Still backward compatibility is broken in gcc 7.