# Linking to stdc++fs with C++20 still necessary when using filesystem?

Tags: c++, gcc, std-filesystem

I began using `experimental::filesystem` when it had just come out and I was advised to link in `stdc++fs` using `target_link_libraries(MyTarget stdc++fs)` in `CMake.` My programme builds either way but may I be breaking something/ doing something unnecessary if I leave out the extra link command?

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476810/build-project-with-experimental-filesystem-using-cmake) was asked three years ago and seems to assume that linking in `stdc++fs` was necessary.

Edit: compiler version is `g++-9 (Homebrew GCC 9.3.0_1) 9.3.0` and `CMake` version is 3.16.

Many thanks!

Comment: I guess it depends on your compiler version. From cppreference, At the very bottom of the File System Library page, you can find:
`Using this library may require additional compiler/linker options. GNU implementation prior to 9.1 requires linking with -lstdc++fs and LLVM implementation prior to LLVM 9.0 requires linking with -lc++fs`
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem#Notes

Comment: Thank you @NicoJ. if you want to write that up as the answer, I shall accept it. Basically, you need to provide a CMake command that checks compiler version a la here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933172/how-can-i-add-a-minimum-compiler-version-requisite

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lifted from my comment:

I guess it depends on your compiler version. From cppreference, At the very bottom of the File System Library page, you can find:

> Using this library may require additional compiler/linker options. GNU
>   implementation prior to 9.1 requires linking with -lstdc++fs and LLVM
>   implementation prior to LLVM 9.0 requires linking with -lc++fs

en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem#Notes

As you mentioned, the following link get more in details about how to check compiler identity in cmake: [How can I add a minimum compiler version requisite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933172/how-can-i-add-a-minimum-compiler-version-requisite)